# Lucene - Combining multi field query with boolean query

Tags: c#, java, lucene.net

I am doing a free text search on my Lucene index using `MultiFieldQueryParser` on 2 fields, this works fine. Below is how I am building the search query:

```
var searchParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(_currentLuceneVersion, new[] { _titleField, _bodyField }, _standardAnalyzer);
Query searchQuery = searchParser.Parse(searchText);
```

I have now added a new field, which is a boolean (1 or 0 as string), and I want my original search to do a boolean filter on the original free text search.

I am thinking that this must be done using a `BooleanQuery` and then doing a combine with the original `MultiFieldQueryParser` and the new `BooleanQuery`.

Is that right way to go about doing this?

Comment: You can also create a `QueryFilter` and give it to `Search` method

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you give me an example of this?

Comment: Like LB said i'd build 2 QueryFilters, one for 0 and one for 1. Then you keep them around and re-use them. You need to rebuild the Filters only when the index changes. QueryFilter caches the matching docs so you should see a performance increase over using a plain BooleanQuery clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of a QueryFilter for a 'false' value

```
QueryFilter falseFilter = new QueryFilter(new TermQuery(new Term("BOOL_FIELD", "0")));
searcher.search(query, falseFilter, maxResults);
```

Comment: can I just ask, is it possible to use multiple filters?

Comment: yes, using the BooleanFilter in the Lucene.net contrib package, it is in the Lucene.Net.Search namespace